# Reloading Cufon after Ajax load, please assist

Tags: ajax, jquery, cufon

I have been trying every possible combination of cufon.replace - Cufon.refresh and Cufon.reload but i just cant seem to get this working. when original page loads cufon does its job, but when Ajax loads new content the cufon is missing. here is my java hope this makes sense to anyone, Cufon fires first, followed by Ajax,

```
    jQuery.noConflict();

/*
  * TYPOGRAPHY
*/

Cufon.set('fontFamily', 'ColaborateLight');
Cufon.replace('h2, #main h3, h4, h5, h6, #slogan, .label', {
    hover: true
});

Cufon.set('fontFamily', 'Colaborate-Medium');
Cufon.replace('#main_home h3', {
    hover: true
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = jQuery('#nav2 li a').each(function(){
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
            jQuery('#content').load(toLoad)
        }                                           
    });

    jQuery('#nav2 li a').click(function(){
    jQuery("#nav2 li a").addClass("current").not(this).removeClass("current");

        var toLoad = jQuery(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        jQuery('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
        jQuery('#load').remove();
        jQuery('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        jQuery('#load').fadeIn('normal');
        window.location.hash = jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(0,jQuery(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            jQuery('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            jQuery('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            jQuery('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;

    });

});
```

and this is the pages in question that im having trouble with.
[Climate Page](http://www.mywildcoast.com/wild-coast-climate.html)
You will see the Ajax loader at the bottom of the page with a secondary menu list.
I'm desperate guys, please help...

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, couldn't get this to work:

```
$("#my_div").load('some-ajax-file.php', Cufon.refresh);
```

But, wrapping Cufon.refresh in a function did the trick:

```
$("#my_div").load('some-ajax-file.php', function() { Cufon.refresh(); });
```

Comment: Just ran into this problem, and your answer did the trick. I was originally trying it the way you were.

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me...

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {  
    Cufon.refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
function showNewContent() {
    Cufon.refresh();
    jQuery('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
}
```

This is also discussed in the cufon api docs - https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API

Answer (score 1):

After ajax response you can simply use

```
Cufon.refresh();
```

That will reload cufon font style

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {  
Cufon('h2'); // or whatever other cufon calls, really...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and to make faster resolution made an in-line CSS

```
 <h5 style="font-family:xxx, Helvetica, sans-serif"></h5>

<style type="text/css">
  @font-face { 
    font-family: SWZ721C; 
    src: url('../../includedfiles/xxx.TTF');
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: MyCustomFont;
    src: url("../../includedfiles/xxx.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() { Cufon.refresh(); });
```

Hope it helps :)